# React Routes v6 cannot load pages on Github-page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <OutletPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainPage />,
        loader: salesLoader
      },
      {
        path: "catalog/:catalogID",
        element: <GoodsPage />,
        loader: goodsLoader,
      },
      {
        path: ":catalog/:goodID",
        element: <GoodPage />,
        loader: goodLoader
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-in',
        element: <SignIn />
      },
      {
        path: 'order',
        element: <Order />
      }
    ]
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

i need to keep `loader` but `createBrowserRouter` isn't nessasary. So problem is: when i deployed my app to `gh-pages` i cannot load any page with 404 error. I searched in the internet what can i do and find a solution like: place `<HashRouter>` and everything will be all right. BUT! when i did it i got error like `You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.`. I am using React Router v6

Also in my react component `Navigation bar` i am using this way of navigation `<a href='/sign-in' />` but `gh-pages` not only do not working with another pages, he even can't load main page

I did try remake my routers the old-fashioned way with `<Routers> <Route /> <Routers>` place `<HasRouter />`(because github pages doesn't work without it). And my main problem that github pages doesn't work without `<HashRoute>` but my app do not working with `<HashRoute>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace `createBrowserRouter` with `createHashRouter`
2. Remove `HashRouter`

```
const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <OutletPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainPage />,
        loader: salesLoader
      },
      {
        path: "catalog/:catalogID",
        element: <GoodsPage />,
        loader: goodsLoader,
      },
      {
        path: ":catalog/:goodID",
        element: <GoodPage />,
        loader: goodLoader
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-in',
        element: <SignIn />
      },
      {
        path: 'order',
        element: <Order />
      }
    ]
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: If I ever had to die for you, I would do it without hesitation. Thank you! You saved me

Comment: and main joke is... i knew about `createHashRouter` but obviously i am too dumb for connect two dots